# "Comprehensive Proof" Math books?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, proof-writing

I haven't read many math books (only the ones required for class and some I picked up on my own) but most all the math books I have read so far leave out important proofs for several Theorems. Sure, proofs should be left as exercises but some Theorems are difficult to prove with lack of mathematical maturity (and I don't like "accepting it" for now and someday learning to prove it).

So is there (or are there) books that have proofs for every Theorem in its specific branch of mathematics? For example, a book on Analysis that has a proof on every theorem (specific to Analysis), from the beginning to the "end"?

Comment: Analysis has an "end"?

Comment: To be frank, wouldn't this apply to basically any textbook that doesn't cover the foundations of math in detail? So for example, I think the Intro to Set Theory book by Hrbacek and Jech basically starts "from ground zero," but most analysis and algebra books don't talk about set-theoretic justifications....

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown That's why I said "end," because Analysis itself doesn't have one (or does it?) but Analysis books do have an end. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: @pseudocydonia I'm speaking about Theorems specific to $X$ branch of math such as Intro to Analysis,  Intro Abstract Algebra, etc.

Comment: I would recommend reading "Foundations of Analysis" by Edmund Landau- and then realizing that this is not really what you want.

Comment: Hardy followed this mantra in his *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. In general writing such a book is difficult and the chances are low that such a book will sell precisely because it won't be recommended by teachers and professors.

Comment: There is actually a book I know of being published for analysis that leaves all the proofs as exercises, but with the "solutions" as it were at the back of each chapter. It will also include a lot of exercises - again with complete solutions. A version like this was created for point set topology and you can find it here, if it is of interest: [link](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/undergraduate-topology-9780198702344?cc=gb&lang=en&)

Comment: @AlgTop Thanks, I will check the topology one. What is the name of the book that will be coming out?

Answer (score 3):

1. [The Real Numbers and Real Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387721762)
   by Ethan D. Bloch
2. [Mathematical Analysis I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319127713) (UNITEXT) 2nd ed. 2015 Edition by Claudio Canuto,‎ Anita Tabacco
3. [Mathematical Analysis II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/331912756X) (UNITEXT) 2nd ed. 2015 Edition
   by Claudio Canuto,‎ Anita Tabacco
4. [Advanced Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847910) (Pure and Applied Undergraduate Texts: the Sally Series) 2nd Revised edition Edition by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick (Author)

I can't explain in details why they are good. Just get them and find it yourself.

Comment: The first one is the best in one variable analysis as far as I know, he covers many important topic that many books often omitted. You can download and see the preface and contents in the springer.com. (warmly warmly recommend!) The 2 and 3, if I remember correct, have solutions for every exercise. 4. makes clear explanation on many topics. I have all these books. I simualtaneously read them whenever I studying analysis.

Comment: If you have get one or several of these, and you're satisfied with them, trusting my advice, I can give you 5.~8. ;)

Comment: I did check contents of the first book you refer. It is indeed impressive.

Comment: Hi @ParamanandSingh. Wow! Haven't you heard about this book? I feel that you are the person who knows many books in analysis. I remember you had suggested the Spivak's Calculus and Hardy's book. :)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Bloch deal with the number system very well. He gives both the constructive way from the Peano axioms and the axiomatic way by ordered field + completness, and he explained it crystal clear! And he also clearly explain the 'story' of transcendal functions. By the way, I'm going to get Hardy's book. But it takes some effort to buy it in Asia..

Comment: Hardy's book is available online if you search enough.

Comment: Since Bloch's book also tries to provide all the proofs it is not going to be a favorite among educators. That's probably one reason it is not popular. Spivak is an exception. Don't know how it managed to be favorite among teachers.

Comment: @Eric I agree, the list is impressive. I will check them out. Also, does anyone know of an intro to applied math book with complete solutions (not necessarily worked out)? I will not be able to take an Applied Math course so I would like to study it on my own with the help of this forum.

Answer (score 2):

As for analysis, Vladimir Zorich's Mathematical Analysis (I and II) and Terence Tao's Analysis (I and II) are very hard-core in the sense that they are totally proof-based  and very comprehensive, and you can always find useful theorems or lemmas proved in these two textbooks. Zorich's Analysis is also famous for both its broad coverage of the application of mathematical principles to physics, and the difficulty of the review problems. It can benifit you greatly if you put great efforts into thinking and solving them independently.

As for linear algebra, I highly recommend the textbook "Linear Algebra 5th Edition" written by Stephen Friedberg, Arnold Insel, and Lawrence Spence. It is true that this books is very expensive (230 Canadian Dollars), but it can explain every concept very clearly and thoroughly prove the theorems. This is also the textbook of my school for elementary algebra. The review problems of this book are also very challenging.

As for other branches of mathematics, Thomas Jech and Karel Hrbacek wrote a book called "Introduction to Set Theory", which uses axiomatic ways to construct set theory and of course is based on proofs of the theorems; also, Jech himself wrote a brick-like book called "Set Theory: The Third Millennium Edition, revised and expanded", and this book covers almost all the important topics  in set theory, from its axiomatic foundation to its most current research outcomes, and is of course proof-based.

This is all that I know. I hope it may help you.